# Change background in wordpress twenty thirteen theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to put a background image to wordpress twenty thirteen theme static home page. I've created a child theme and put the following code in *style.css* in child theme.

```
body{
    background:url('wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Road-604x270.jpg');
}

#main{
     background:url('wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Road-604x270.jpg');
}
```

I have uploaded a image *Road.jpg* through *upload media* in wordpress. The file along with its created different sized files are located in the above mentioned path under *wp-content*. I have decided to use the original sized image which is of 604X270 pixels, but the background image is not being displayed. Am I making any mistake defining the path of the image or is their any mistake in the code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the whole url:

```
#main{
    background-image: url(http://your_domain/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Road-604x270.jpg);/* without '' */
}
```

instead of

```
 #main{
        background-image: url('wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Road-604x270.jpg');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting a background image, make sure that container has some height, or not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the whole url like Aminesrine said, but check the name of your image, because you said that has uploaded a image named Road.jpg and want to use the original size, then try:

```
#main{
    background-image: url(http://domain/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Road.jpg)
}
```

Comment: He said the original size of the image is 604X270 pixels

Comment: I found out the file name form wordpress content folder. As uploading images through _wordpress media upload_ always creates four image files whose name starts with the original name but ends with the resolution value added to it. However, @Aminesrine's solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you guys.